# Beamer frame: adding something to the last slide

Tags: beamer, overlays

How can one create a new environment `eframe` so that some element is added (the place can be hardcoded) on the last slide of the frame?

Suppose I have many frames with lots of `\pause`s:

```
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    one\pause two
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    one\pause two\pause three
\end{frame}
```

Replacing `frame` by `eframe` I would like to end up with the following behaviour:

```
\begin{frame}{Frame 1{\onslide<3>{END}}}
    one\pause two
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2{\onslide<4>{END}}}
    one\pause two\pause three
\end{frame}
```

I don't want to hardcode this numbers `3` and `4` because if later I decide to add more `pause`s, I would have to change those numbers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make my self clear enough earlier. Unfortunately I won't be here for the next hours to comment/accept possible solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `eframe` environment defined below works just like a normal frame but appends *(END)* on the last slide of that frame.

This solution rests on mainly two tricks:

1. accessing the value of the `beamerpauses` counter (which, at a given point of a `frame` environment, contains the number of overlay specifications used so far in that frame) only at the very end of the environment, in order to get the total number of overlay specifications in that frame; and
2. [Joseph Wright's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130072/21891) for programmatically changing the frame title mid frame.

You can easily redefined the `eframe` environment to suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\augmentframetitle}[1]
{%
    \expandafter\frametitle\expandafter%
    {\beamer@frametitle #1}%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{eframe}
{%
    \begin{frame}
}{%
    \augmentframetitle{\ \onslide<\value{beamerpauses}>{(END)}}         
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{eframe}
    \frametitle{My last topic}
        foo\\
        \pause
        bar
    \end{eframe}
\end{document}
```