# How can I effect a new frame title, mid frame, based on the original one?

Tags: beamer

At some stage of my `frame` environment, I want to access the current value of the frame title, and then construct and effect a new frame title based on the original value.

Sounds convoluted, doesn't it? I hope this will better explain what I'm trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Foo}                    % original title: Foo
    ...
    % Here, I want, for instance, to append "bar" to the 'current' frame title.
    % \insertframetitle is defined here
    \let\currtitle\insertframetitle     % to avoid recursion
    \frametitle{\currtitle bar}         % desired new title: Foobar
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I thought `\let\currtitle\insertframetitle` would be enough to keep me out of trouble, but I get the error

```
Undefined control sequence. \insertframetitle
```

and I don't understand why...

The original title should only be used to construct the new one and is not meant to be printed unchanged in the output. The reason I must solve this problem is that I want to define a new frame environment in which the original frame title (provided by the user) is processed and used to construct the *effective* frame title, based on the contents of the frame environment.

Comment: Do you want the frame(s) to be produced only with the new title or with both old and new? The way `beamer` works the latter case is going to be hard work.

Comment: @JosephWright Only with the new title. This is for defining a new frame environment in which the original frame title (provided by the user) is processed and used to construct the *effective* frame title, based on the contents of the `frame` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `beamer` doesn't define `\insertframetitle` just to the text, and resets/removes definitions at various points. What your therefore want to do is re-run `\frametitle` with the stored text of the frame name, `\beamer@frametitle`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\augmentframtitle}[1]{%
  \expandafter\frametitle\expandafter
    {\beamer@frametitle #1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
  ...
  \augmentframtitle{bar}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it! So simple a solution, yet so elusive :)